# How to save coordinates to Firebase

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase, android-studio

I am trying to save location in Firebase. I can't find any information about how to save location in Firebase. And I develop my in Android Studio in Java. I put a button in layout and when I click to this button it should send coordinates to Firebase. But I don't know anything about saving data to Firebase.

Please if you can help me I will be happy!

Comment: Pleae post what have you tried so far

Comment: When I click to button in-app then it should send coordinates to firebase

Comment: More information such as what platform you are programming for (i.e. web, iOS, Android, etc.), and how your "location"s are represented would be helpful.

Comment: I'm developing app in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, just so you know your question is WAY too general and this code is not complete by any means; as large as the response is.  It is enough to get you going you will need to do more research.  I hope this helps. What is not included is the UI to allow a user to save the location from a map or whatever the source is.

Also not included is the authentication do do this [Oauth] that is a whole separate issue.  If I were you I would start with a tutorial that adds and shows data, get that working then substitute the data with location

[tutorial](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/cloud-firestore/part-1-introduction)

There are lots of steps, you might want to start with a tutorial, there are lots of good ones out there.

your db ref:

```
 mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


  final DatabaseReference locationsRef = mFirebaseDatabaseReference
            .child(USERS_CHILD.concat("/" + mFirebaseAuth.getUid()).concat("/locations"));

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Location> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Location>()
                    .setQuery(locationsRef
                            .orderByChild("name"), parser)
                    .build();


mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Location, 
PlacesFragment.LocationViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        public PlacesFragment.LocationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, 
        final int position) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
            PlacesFragment.LocationViewHolder holder = new 
            PlacesFragment.LocationViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_item, 
            viewGroup, false));

            Log.d(TAG, "viewHolder created");

            return holder;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(final PlacesFragment.LocationViewHolder viewHolder,
                                        int position, Location location) {

            if (location.getName() != null) {
                viewHolder.locationNameTextView.setText(location.getName());
                viewHolder.locationNameTextView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.locationAddressTextView.setText(location.getAddress());

viewHolder.locationLatTextView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));

viewHolder.locationLongTextView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            int count = super.getItemCount();
            return count;

        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChanged() {

            Log.d(TAG, "OnDataChanged");

            mLandmarks.clear();

            ArrayList<Location> arr = new ArrayList<Location>();

            for (int i = 0; i < mFirebaseAdapter.getSnapshots().toArray().length; i++) {
                Location loc = mFirebaseAdapter.getItem(i);
                arr.add(loc);
                mLandmarks.put(loc.getName(), new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), 
loc.getLongitude()));
            }

           if (mService != null) {
               mService.setLocationsData(arr);
               Log.d(TAG, "onDataChanged: updating locations");
           } else {
               mService_not_updated = true;
               Log.d(TAG, "onDataChanged: not updating locations");
           }


            // Get the geofences used.
            populateGeofenceList();

            super.onDataChanged();

        }
    };

    mFirebaseAdapter.startListening();
```

database rules so each user can have their own list of locations:

```
// These rules grant access to a node matching the authenticated
// user's ID from the Firebase auth token
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
    "$uid": {
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is how you might store a location:

```
 private void storeLocation(com.wfs.android.walkingjinni.Location location) {
    com.wfs.android.walkingjinni.Location loc = new com.wfs.android.walkingjinni.Location(

            mFirebaseUserId,
            location.getName(),
            location.getAddress(),
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()
            ,location.getPlaceId());

    mFirebaseDatabaseReference
            .child(PlacesFragment.USERS_CHILD).child(mFirebaseUserId)
            .child(PlacesFragment.LOCATIONS_CHILD).push().setValue(loc);

    Log.d(TAG, location.getAddress() + " stored from map");

}
```

and this is what a location might be:

```
@Keep
public class Location implements Parcelable {

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Location>() {
    public Location createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Location(in);
    }

    public Location[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Location[size];
    }
};

private String id;
private String user_id;
private String name;
private String address;
private double latitude, longitude;
private String place_id = "";

private Location(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readString();
    user_id = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();
    address = in.readString();
    latitude = in.readDouble();
    longitude = in.readDouble();
    place_id = in.readString();
}

public Location() {

}

/// used for onCreate for the home location, nothing else
public Location(String name, String address,
                double latitude, double longitude, String placeId) {

    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.place_id = placeId;

}


public Location(
        String userId,
        String name,
        String address,
        double latitude, double longitude, String placeId) {

    this.user_id = userId;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.place_id = placeId;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.user_id = userId;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getPlaceId() {
    return place_id;
}

public void setPlaceId(String placeId) {
    this.place_id = placeId;
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(id);
    parcel.writeString(user_id);
    parcel.writeString(name);
    parcel.writeString(address);
    parcel.writeDouble(latitude);
    parcel.writeDouble(longitude);
    parcel.writeString(place_id);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Location{" +
            " id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", user_id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", address='" + address + '\'' +
            ", latitude='" + latitude + '\'' +
            ", longitude='" + longitude + '\'' +
            ", place_id='" + place_id + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public android.location.Location getLocation() {
    android.location.Location loc = new android.location.Location("");
    loc.setLatitude(this.getLatitude());
    loc.setLongitude(this.getLongitude());
    return loc;


}
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I can do my project! One more question what is db ref?

Comment: updated, good luck

Comment: What is  private void storeLocation(com.wfs.android.walkingjinni.Location location)?

Comment: it is only an example of what you might need to do in the activity to store a new location in firebase. then the observer updates when the new location is added.  If you have a recycler view of locations...